# Parse Massive CSV With PHP But Deal With Line Breaks Within Enclosures

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I have a CSV parser which handles files of any size by chunking the file into pieces and then reading each line using fgets() to grab each line data and str_getcsv() to return each line as an array. It has been able to handle files with over 200,000 lines without a problem.

However, I am now dealing with some files which contain line breaks within enclosures. The problem is that fgets() reads a line but stops when it sees a line break. So my system fails. It then continues to read the lines of the field which has the line breaks and it continues to process those fields as if they are new lines in the CSV. Ouch.

So, I am not sure of the best way to proceed. I will need to continue to chunk my files to deal with the massive size however I cannot switch to another parsing library which deals more elegantly with line breaks, such as https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php because this type of parser attempts to parse an ENTIRE CSV file at once which is not suitable for the size of file I am dealing with.

I am looking for suggestions on a specific strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to keep fgets() in use so I did the following to solve this:

- Detect if the current line has an unclosed enclosure on the last field
- If so, continue and append the NEXT line(s) onto the current one until the enclosure is detected.
- Process the 'set' of lines as one single line.
- Repeat

Working well for me. Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: Feels clumsy but I did not find something better so far.